# Looping over clickable plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following class which I intend to use in labelling specific parts of a time series.

```
class Labeler(object):
    def __init__(self, accel_data, vline=0):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))

        self.accel_data = accel_data
        x_ = np.arange(len(self.accel_data))

        self.plot, = plt.plot(x_, self.accel_data, picker=100)
        plt.xlim(0, len(self.accel_data)-1)

        self.final_loc = 0
        self.vline_loc = 0
        self.vline = plt.axvline(self.vline_loc, color='red')

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._onclick)

        self.button_next = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.78, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Next', color='#32CD32')
        self.button_next.on_clicked(self._nextbutton)

        self.button_done = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.65, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Done', color='orange')
        self.button_done.on_clicked(self._donebutton)
        plt.show(block=True)

        self.starts = []

    def _onclick(self, event):
        self.final_loc = self.vline_loc
        self.vline_loc = int(event.xdata)
        self.vline.set_xdata(self.vline_loc)

    def _nextbutton(self, event):
        self.starts.append(['code', self.final_loc])
        n = np.random.randint(1000)
        self.plot.set_xdata(np.arange(n))
        self.plot.set_ydata(np.random.rand(n))
        self.plot.set_title(str(n))

   def _donebutton(self, event):
        plt.close() # close to stop plot
```

Now, I want to use this in an ipython notebook so that I can use it in a loop like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    l = Labeler(np.random.rand(1000))
    print(l.starts) # print the locs of vertical lines
    cont = input("Press any key to continue")
```

My problem is that when I loop over the plot, it waits until the loop is finished before displaying the plot. What I want it to do is open a single plot, determine parts using the red line, and then proceed to the next plot. Please let me know how this can be accomplished. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest plotting in a thread.

Comment: @LiranFunaro what do you mean by that?

Comment: Open a thread an run your code there.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for jupyter notebook

The problem in a notebook is that the interactive figure prevents further code from being executed. The only solution I can think of is to let the figure take over control over the updates.
The following would be an example (I'm sure it's not what you actually wanted, but I had problems understanding the purpose of some of the code, so it does something similar). The idea would be to provide **all** the data already to the class, which can then loop through it.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np


class Labeler(object):
    def __init__(self, data, vline=0):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
        self.ax = self.fig.gca()
        self.i = 0
        self.data = data 
        
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._onclick)
        self.button_next = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.78, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Next', color='#32CD32')
        self.button_next.on_clicked(self._nextbutton)
        self.button_done = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.65, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Done', color='orange')
        self.button_done.on_clicked(self._donebutton)

        self.starts = []
        plt.show()
        

    def _nextbutton(self, event):
        self.i
        self.final_loc = 0
        self.vline_loc = 0
        self.accel_data = self.data[self.i % len(data)]
        self.x = np.arange(len(self.accel_data))
        plt.xlim(0, len(self.accel_data)-1)
        self.plot, = self.ax.plot(self.x, self.accel_data, picker=100)
        self.vline = self.ax.axvline(self.vline_loc, color='red')
        self.starts.append(['code', self.final_loc])
        self.ax.set_title(str(self.i))
        self.i += 1
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        

    def _onclick(self, event):
        self.final_loc = self.vline_loc
        self.vline_loc = int(event.xdata)
        self.vline.set_xdata(self.vline_loc)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


    def _donebutton(self, event):
        #plt.close() # close to stop plot
        self.ax.clear()
        pass

data = []
for i in range(5):
    data.append(np.random.rand(60+10*i))
l = Labeler(data)
```

[image]

#### Solution for a console:

The following code runs fine for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np


class Labeler(object):
    def __init__(self, accel_data, vline=0):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
        self.ax = self.fig.gca()
        self.accel_data = accel_data
        x_ = np.arange(len(self.accel_data))

        self.plot, = plt.plot(x_, self.accel_data, picker=100)
        plt.xlim(0, len(self.accel_data)-1)

        self.final_loc = 0
        self.vline_loc = 0
        self.vline = plt.axvline(self.vline_loc, color='red')

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._onclick)

        self.button_next = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.78, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Next', color='#32CD32')
        self.button_next.on_clicked(self._nextbutton)

        self.button_done = Button(plt.axes([0.85, 0.65, 0.05, 0.1]), 'Done', color='orange')
        self.button_done.on_clicked(self._donebutton)
        
        self.starts = []
        plt.show(block=True)

        

    def _onclick(self, event):
        self.final_loc = self.vline_loc
        self.vline_loc = int(event.xdata)
        self.vline.set_xdata(self.vline_loc)

    def _nextbutton(self, event):
        self.starts.append(['code', self.final_loc])
        n = np.random.randint(1000)
        self.plot.set_xdata(np.arange(n))
        self.plot.set_ydata(np.random.rand(n))
        self.ax .set_title(str(n))

    def _donebutton(self, event):
        plt.close() # close to stop plot
        
for i in range(5):
    l = Labeler(np.random.rand(1000))
    print(l.starts) # print the locs of vertical lines
    cont = raw_input("Press any key to continue")
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it works when ran from the terminal but I want to use it inside an ipython notebook..

Comment: Which backend are you using`?

Comment: The backend is `nbAgg`

Comment: Ok, sorry for confusion. Do you want me to delete the answer?

Comment: that's fine. no problem

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution for jupyter notebook. It's not the same program structure anymore but may still be what you need.

Comment: I don't think it will work cause I will be looping through multiple arrays and as a result, the plot will be too cluttered if I append all of them together as one.

Comment: My answer only gives you the principle solution. You need to see for yourself what to show where and when. E.g. you can clear the previous line before showing a new one if you want to avoid too many lines in the plot.